# WebMatrix error updating NuGet

Tags: asp.net, nuget, webmatrix

I'm having a strange problem since two days. I'm using WebMatrix 2 (latest, all updates checked). I run NuGet to check for available updates. I see a few updates, everything gets updated properly, except for NuGet.Core.

I see the latest NuGet version 2.2.0 is available. I run the update and it gives me error. Says unable to find a version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Administration that is compatible with NuGet.Core.2.2.0. The detail of this error is:

```
An error occurred.

Updating 'NuGet.Core 1.6.2' to 'Nuget.Core 2.2.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Administration' that is compatible with 'Nuget.Core 2.2.0'.

System.InvalidOperationException: Updating 'NuGet.Core 1.6.2' to 'Nuget.Core 2.2.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Administration' that is compatible with 'Nuget.Core 2.2.0'.
   at NuGet.InstallWalker.OnBeforePackageWalk(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.PackageWalker.Walk(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.InstallWalker.ResolveOperations(IPackage package)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.Execute(IPackage package, IPackageOperationResolver resolver)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.AddPackageReference(IPackage package, Boolean ignoreDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.UpdatePackageReference(IPackage package, Boolean updateDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.UpdatePackageReference(String packageId, Func`1 resolvePackage, Boolean updateDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions, Boolean targetVersionSetExplicitly)
   at NuGet.ProjectManager.UpdatePackageReference(String packageId, SemanticVersion version, Boolean updateDependencies, Boolean allowPrereleaseVersions)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.PackageManagement.WebProjectManager.<>c__DisplayClass4.<UpdatePackage>b__3()
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.PackageManagement.WebProjectManager.PerformLoggedAction(Action action)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.PackageManagement.WebProjectManager.UpdatePackage(IPackage package, AppDomain appDomain)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.NuGetPackageManager.UpdatePackage(IPackage package)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.NuGetGallery.ExtensibleNuGetPackageManager.UpdatePackage(IPackage package)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.NuGetModel.UpdatePackage(IPackage package, Boolean isFeatured, Boolean inDetails)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.PackageViewModel.ExecuteAction(Boolean inDetails)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.NuGet.NuGetViewModel.ExecuteNuGetAction(Object completionAction)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InvokeFuture(Object futureAsObj)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

What does it mean? What's wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because  http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Administration package has dependency on nuget.core NuGet.Core (≥ 1.6.2 && < 1.7) which won't allow it to update it to a higher version.
I see there is already an issue raised here http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/435 for making it compatible with 2.x version.

Comment: Ok. means everyone is having this problem. I'll wait for them to release the Administration update. Thanks for your info.